# Failing to reach RESTful service with Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly, war

I'm trying to run a simple Spring Boot application on Wildfly 13.0.0, but I always get a 404 error when trying to reach any REST urls.

Here's my app class:

```
package com.application.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;


@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApp.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(applicationClass);
    }

    private static Class<ExampleApp> applicationClass = ExampleApp.class;


}

@RestController
class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {

        return "Hi " + name + " !";

    }
}
```

And here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>example</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>application-example</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

The .war is deployed correctly and I can reach a html index page I created if I go to [localhost:8080/application-example/index.html](http://localhost:8080/application-example/index.html) but if I try [localhost:8080/application-example/hello](http://localhost:8080/application-example/hello) or [localhost:8080/application-example/hello/myName](http://localhost:8080/application-example/hello/myName) or even the original name with 0.0.1 Snapshot at the end I always get a 404.

Of course this also happens for RestController classes inside inner packages but in the above example we are in the same package so I don't think it is a visibility/scanning issue.

Here's my application.properties as requested:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/example
spring.datasource.username=root@localhost
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

server.servlet.contextPath=/application-example
```

Am I missing something? If you need further details please ask away.

Comment: your requestmapping suggests `/hello/{name}`, so did you only try to send a request to `/hello`? Do you have a mapping to `/hello` as well? If not, then try `localhost:8080/application-example/hello/myName`

Comment: hey @IvoVidovic, yes I also tried that one, sorry for not specifying it in my original question. Doesn't work.

Comment: Please post your application properties file too. I am just wondering if you have server context path rightly setup.

Comment: @AmithKumar Just posted it

Comment: You deployed your application as "application-example" on your Tomcat and added `server.servlet.contextPath=/application-example` specifically to the application properties, is this correct? I am not 100 % sure, since I cannot deploy it on a tomcat currently, but could you try out: `localhost:8080/application-example/application-example/hello/myName`?

Comment: spring.datasource.username=root@localhost, here you have problem. i guess your password is root but you are putting root@localhost, can you please check this as well.

Comment: @IvoVidovic I also had that guess but I still get 404.

Comment: Do you see any error in server log of Wildfly when deploying the war ?

Comment: No errors and on the Wildfly console the war is up and running with status 'ok '. Plus, I just tried out running the app with the standalone Spring Boot Tomcat server and it works fine, so it really should be some configuration I'm missing on the Wildfly side.

Comment: Can you try this, [Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-weblogic) has special instruction for Weblogic to do this, just wondering if it applies for Wildfly too:

`public class ExampleApp extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer`

Comment: Just tried it and doesn't work @AmithKumar

Comment: I found this project on github for [spring-boot with wildfly](https://github.com/gshipley/bootwildfly). Check if you are able to run this ? If yes, then you have something to compare with. Otherwise I will install the Wildfly on my system (if you can provide your version#) later, and if you can check-in your code on github. I will try to run it on my machine.

Comment: following the configuration on that project I got it to work, thanks @AmithKumar

Comment: Great, glad was able to help. Updated the answer for easy future reference by anyone facing similar issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [Spring Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file), you are missing on below:

> A popular subject is that many people still wish to generate WAR files to be deployed inside containers. Both of these plugins support that as well. Essentially, you have to reconfigure your project to produce a WAR file and declare the embedded container dependencies as "provided". This ensures that the relevant embedded container dependencies aren’t included in the WAR file.
> To build a war file that is both executable and deployable into an external container, you need to mark the embedded container dependencies as “provided”, as shown in the following example:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

**NOTE:** You don't need exclusions.

**UPDATE**
Follow this working [project](https://github.com/gshipley/bootwildfly) on `github` for `spring-boot with wildfly` to compare the missing configuration.